# Can I export content images with SXA Creative Exchange?

Tags: sxa

I am playing with SXA Creative Exchange and discovered that it exports only images stored in `Theme` media folder. That is fine for prototyping, when page is created by designer.

In real sites, Content Authors do not want to mix design and content assets. They build pages using real content and still want to use Creative Exchange to apply styles. When such pages are exported, they do not look nice and design can be broken.

Can SXA export images referenced by components if they are stored in different folder to keep page layout?

Update: let me clarify with screenshot what is Exported what is not in my case:
[image]

I do not want keep all my Images in `theme` folder.

Comment: Have you read here for importing images? https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/11/designing/creative_exchange/change_a_site_design_using_creative_exchange

Comment: @MichaelWest I read that documentation. It does not cover my question (please point me to right statement it I miss something). My issue is not related to import. I want Export to include not only Theme, but real content images. Theme is not enough to build pages.

Comment: I just tested with exporting in both Authoring and Agency mode and saw the page level image get exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer for you question is **YES** but for SXA **1.0**.

From the screenshot, I can see that you are using **1.1**.

I tried to reproduce your scenario and I was able to reproduce the same behaviour.

I tried it on **1.0** as well and it does not occur on initial release.

In my opinion, this is a regression and should be reported to Sitecore Support if you wish get some support package (if it will be possible).

@michael-west wrote that it works fine on his machine. I'm assuming that he is using **1.0**, if not then it is interesting why it is working for him.

Answer (score -1):

if images are added in the prototyping they will get exported with that theme. 
see the images folder in the tree right above scripts. with exception of page and home index.html files, my understanding is that all other customizations need to happen within the themes directory with the exception of base themes which should never be modified.

If this is NOT CORRECT, please provide some helpful feedback as the documentation is completely lacking and this answer is based on actual testing.

[image]

Comment: Can someone confirm whether this is correct and if going to downvote please explain why.

Comment: You refer to images inside Theme folder. My question was about regular content images. They IMHO should be separated from design (theme) and stored in separate folder. In you case under Site1 folder.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski thanks for your feedback.